# Central Limit Theorem on the Circle

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

I am interested in a circular equivalent to the classical CLT. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition telling when a normalized sum of circular distributed  random variables converges to a WrappedNormal distributed random variable? That is, what conditions do circular i.i.d. random vectors $X_i$ have to satisfy in order to ensure
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \mod 2\pi$$
converges to a WrappedNormal distributed random variable. Is there a similar result for (hyper-)spheres?

Comment: Please define "normalized sum of circular distributed random variables".

Comment: I mean a similar summation scheme as in the case of the classical CLT. Added it to the original post.

Comment: How do you define the division on the circle?

Comment: It seems that 5 upvoters know the answer to the query formulated twice in the comments above.

Comment: @D.Thomine: Not at all. In order to account for the fact, that $X_i$ is circular, we can simply use a real-valued random vector restricted to $[0, 2\pi)$. Thus, we use the classical division for real numbers. The summation scheme presented in my post obviously yields again a random vector restricted to $[0, 2\pi)$.

Comment: Then the classical CLT applies and we are left with no question at all.

Comment: I don't think there will be a convergence to a wrapped normal - if anything we may try to show a convergence to the uniform distribution on the circle and the conditions required for that.

Comment: @Sun: There actually is a convergence to WrappedNormal. Consider a circular random variable $Y:=X\ \text{mod}\ 2\pi$, where $X$ is a standard non-circular random variable with finite variance. Thus, a properly normalized sum of i.i.d. copies of $X$ converges (in distirbution) to a Gaussian random variable.Now, if you do the same with i.i.d. copies of $Y$ and append $\text{mod}\ 2\pi$ at the end of the summation scheme and you'll end up with a summation scheme converging to a wrapped normal distribution.